# Tasks Roll up across Farm, site collection

Tags: tasks, aggregation, cross-site

We have OOTB "task lists" in many sites used by the same set of users.

We have a farm with "x" site collections and "x" sites with-in them without any changes to the default content type.

We would like to roll up the pending tasks and show it in a single web part placed in default portal page.

What would be best way to do this task rollup when we have multiple site collections.

Other Details:
Security is driven by AD groups placed in SP groups.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use Search for this task - it's the fastest and most efficient way. Only downside is a slight update delay (until it's incrementally indexed agina).

Comment: we've had the same requirements and we also preferred search option. although it's relevant to STD or ENT versions - not sure Foundation can support it

Answer (score 5):

There are a few products in the market that currently do this, for example Lightning Conductor by Lightning Tools: http://www.lightningtools.com/lightning-conductor-2010-web-part.aspx. This tool (I think) can even rollup across web applications too.

Answer (score 2):

There are different choices:

1. Search - not percise
2. Cycle over site collections with SPSiteDataQuery
3. Pre-aggregation to root site in each site collection with cycle over site collections

Main problem in query over sitecollection - each site collectiom can be in different Content Database, witch can be on a different server.

Answer (score 2):

Im on the search wagon here.

A way of avoiding the the indexing delay, you could build your own [custom federated search web part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc806021%28v=office.12%29.aspx) that looks at SharePoint through the API (SPSiteDataQuery)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Good free Option with some configurabiity:

[SharePoint User Toolkit: Tasks Lists Roll-up for SharePoint 2010](http://usermanagedsolutions.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit/Pages/SP2010-Tasks-Lists-Rollup.aspx#)